# HTTP query string separating fields with "?"

Tags: javascript, http

Just encountered a website where HTTP query strings used in links have the form

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/?foo=A?bar=B
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/index.php/?foo=A?foo=B
```

The site is based on Joomla and I do not have access to the source code. My guess is that they are doing something fancy JavaScript there, but I couldn't verify this.

So, my question is: Is there any case where a query separating fields with `?` instead of `&` is valid?

Comment: I think their site is just busted. Those URLs are invalid.

Comment: According to RFC3986 where gen-delims and sub-delims are defined: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986